# ifl parameter does not work in my firebase dynamic link

Tags: ios, firebase

I followed this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually and create my dynamic link. I add "ifl" param to the end of my dynamic link like this "...&afl=google.com". However, when my app is not installed in my Iphone, my site didn't redirect to google.com as instruction. So I wonder:

- Is my "ifl" parameter true?
- Do I need to handle "ifl" parameter in Swift Code? And how do I handle "ifl" parameter if needed.

My dynamic link should redirect me to the url I've configured in "ifl" parameter of my dynamic link.

Answer (score 0):

> like this "...&afl=google.com"

`afl` is the Android Fallback Link, make sure to use `ifl` (iOS Fallback Link).

Comment: yes, thank you. But I realise that 'ifl' param just work when app is not install and the dynamic link to preview page. When we click "ok" in preview page link, it will redirect us to the url we configure in "ifl" param

Comment: it is not working for me also, how did you solve your problem